# HAVING skipping certain numbers from an alias

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query that takes a table that contains a `votes` column and ranks them 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and so on. I want to limit the ranks to the top 3 items, however when I use `HAVING`, it appears to skip over even numbers or even bump up to the next number if I were to use `HAVING rank <= 6`.

```
SELECT `category`, 
       `year`, 
       `month`, `votes`, 
       @prev := @curr, 
       @curr := `votes`, 
       @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank + @i) AS `rank`, 
       IF(@prev <> `votes`, @i:=1, @i:= @i+1) AS `counter`
FROM `photo_contest`
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 1, @i := 0) `tmp_tbl`
WHERE `category` = 'World Up Close' 
  AND `year` = '2017' 
  AND `month` = 'April' 
  AND `votes` > 0
HAVING `rank` <= 3
ORDER BY `votes` DESC
```

It may be an issue with our server's PHP installation as it uses a much older MySQL library (5.1.73) than the server that is currently running (5.6.35), but I am not sure. I've had issues with a previous question using similar queries.

Comment: You can try to use `LIMIT 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `HAVING` together with `GROUP BY`. In this case you need to use a subquery without  `HAVING`.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT <your query> ORDER BY `votes` DESC) as T
WHERE rank <= 3
```